# Lighthouse eager loading relations

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I have been trying to migrate my old API into GraphQl and i am trying to eager load just once but with graphql lighthouse i couldnt find properway

my model

```
public function getMeta($name, $defaultValue = null)
{
    if (!$this->relationLoaded('metas')) {
        return $defaultValue;
    }

    return $this->metas->where('name', $name)->first()->value ?? $defaultValue;
}
```

previously i have been using laravel jsonResources

```
'built_year' => $this->getMeta('built_year'),
            'floors' => $this->getMeta('floors'),
            'cabins' => $this->getMeta('cabins'),
```

Using this there is one one request made for metas table

but now using graphql it is making each db req with each `$this->getMeta` call
my schema

```
type Cruise{
built_year : GetMeta @field(resolver:"App\\GraphQL\\Types\\GetMetaTypes@get")
    floors : GetMeta @field(resolver:"App\\GraphQL\\Types\\GetMetaTypes@get")
    cabins : GetMeta @field(resolver:"App\\GraphQL\\Types\\GetMetaTypes@get")
}

type GetMeta{
    value : String
}
```

Custom type

```
public function get($cruise,$next,$a,$b)
    {
        $cruise->load("metas");
        return ['value' => $cruise->getMeta($b->fieldName) ];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your last method you are reloading the relation every time: `$cruise->load("metas")`. What you should do is load the relation only once. You can do that with `$cruise->loadMissing('metas')`. Use single quotes whenever you can.

Comment: its querying multiple times i couldnt find the same way i did with rest api

Comment: It's making multiple queries when you put `$cruise->loadMissing('metas')`?

Comment: yes same like loadMissing  looks like calling each resolver is making each new db query